# Long multi-part book series with humans travelling the galaxy trading but not remembering where earth is, lots of technological progress

Tags: story-identification, books

Long multi-part book series where humans are on a massive hive ship and the location of earth has been lost, towards the end you find out there is a supercomputer/ai in a base that has been built around a star/black hole (I can't remember). I think there are multiple super ai-s running different parts of the universe, and their only entertainment is taking races off of their home planets and making them fight, over the course of thousands of years - this is why earth is lost. Some of the books focus on someone in a trader ship, and then (foundation style) another section of books has a new main character 100s of years later. At some point they discover earth has been hiding itself for when its technology is needed, and they are able to use the old ships which have cloaking technology and railguns, giving them a massive advantage against all the current ships (human and alien) which are based on plasma weapons and plasma shields. I remember there being multiple series leading into one another.

I first read them about 8 years ago, and I think they were written in 2000-2010 (or at least the majority probably were). I took them out from an ebook library service - I don't think it was the most successful series ever. there were a lot of books though, probably at least 3 different parts of at least 4 books each

Comment: What often helps with an id is if you can remember things like the names of characters, or planets, or any similar details that might help jog someone's memory. As it is your description is rather general and there are many scifi books about "a search for lost Earth".